# How to stop gravity forms from sending emails in html code?

Tags: html, text, gravityforms, email-spec

I created a contact form at my website using gravity forms. When they are sent to my email, they arrive in html code. How can I correct that so that they are in text?

I have looked up the problem and solutions at google and youtube and have had no luck in finding a solution to the problem.